# Access the inList-values in View [Grails]

Tags: grails

i want to access the inList-values which i set in domain, in my view. Like this:

```
<g:countrySelect name="SelectState" keys="${incidentInstance?.state.toList()}" value="${incidentInstance?.state}"/>
```

But it dont work...(any idea?)

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are using `<g:countrySelect>` instead of `<g:select>`

To get the inList values (from your *constraints* definition) you do something like this

```
<g:select name="state" from="${incidentInstance.constraints.state.inList}" 
          value="${incidentInstance?.state}"/>
```